# Android Why I get 3 dots at the end of my text in a TextView

Tags: java, android

I use localisation in my android application and with some of the translations, the text doesn't fit into the TextView and without me specifying it, it adds three dots to the end of it. I know it does this because the text doesn't fit, but I haven't specified it to do this. I'm trying to scale the text to fit but it's not working, Can someone tell me why, it would add the three dots to the end instead of scaling it to fit. My code works perfectly for all other text that doesn't fit but two languages.

I can upload code but it works fine for the rest of my localisation, I just want to know why it would add three dots to the end? Thanks

**Edit:**

It's a custom layout for the header.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/title_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/title_gradient"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:tag="title" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:background="@color/solid_red"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:text="@string/Hearing_Test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/info_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:onClick="infoView"
    android:src="@drawable/info" >
</ImageButton>
```

Style:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background" tools:targetApi="11">@drawable/title_gradient</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/title_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator" tools:targetApi="11">@null</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Java class to scale text:

```
public void setTitleTextSize(final int textId, final Boolean displayInfoButton){
    infoButton = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.info_button);
    titleText = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.title_text);

    if(!displayInfoButton){
        infoButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    ViewTreeObserver customTitleScale = titleText.getViewTreeObserver();

    customTitleScale.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            final int infoWidth = infoButton.getMeasuredWidth();
            if(infoWidth !=0 || !displayInfoButton){
                ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11.0){
                            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
                            ((Activity) context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true);
                            actionBarWidth = ((Activity) context).getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(tv.resourceId);
                        }

                        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                        Display Screen = ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                        Screen.getMetrics(metrics);
                        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

                        if(displayInfoButton){
                            titleWidth = screenWidth - infoWidth - actionBarWidth;
                        } else {
                            titleWidth = screenWidth - actionBarWidth;
                        }

                        titleText.setText(textId);
                        String text = ((Activity) context).getResources().getString(textId);
                        titleText.setMaxWidth(titleWidth);
                        Log.d("TextView Width", "Width: " + titleWidth);

                        TextPaint paint = titleText.getPaint();
                        Rect rect = new Rect();
                        int textLength = text.length();
                        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, textLength, rect);
                        float width = rect.left + rect.right;
                        Log.d("Text length pixels", "Pixels " + width);


                        if(rect.width() > titleWidth){

                            float scale = (float) titleWidth / (float) rect.width();
                            float textSize = titleText.getTextSize();       
                            float scaleSize = (float) (textSize * (scale*0.8));     
                            titleText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, scaleSize);

                        }
                    }
                });
                infoButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

In the java class the `if(rect.width() > titleWidth)` allows the scaling to happen, it works everywhere except for two languages where it says that the rect width is smaller than the titleWidth, when it blatantly isn't!

Screetshot:

Issue is that there is space to the left of the textView in red that I don't want and don't know how to remove.

[image: Screenshoot of Header]

Comment: Show your layout.xml with TextView

Comment: I no it's my menu if you look at the java code, I take that into account

Comment: I just tested it on a smaller older phone and it's fine, it seems to just be the nexus 5 when the menu is at the top right corner. I still don't know why it's adding margin to the left of the screen on the nexus 5

Answer (score 0):

He won't scale to fit. If you want to do this, you must do it manually. You can change the `ellipsize` property to define if you want to see the ... or not.

Comment: COuld you show me an example please? Now I saw something the was a class just to resize text in a textView but it was huge, I didn't think I needed so much code just to scale the text in a textview. the way I've done it works for all the other localisation bar two languages, It's literally two lines throughout the entire app that aren't working properly

Comment: I have another question, Why won't my textView go to the very left side of my screen, there's no padding or margins but it won't align to the left even when I use `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`, why is this?

Comment: an example of using of ellipsize would be like:  `android:ellipsize: start`

Comment: About align parent left you have to see that there is the TextView field and its content. If you want to align the content left, you should put gravity on it. AlignParentLeft is putting the field in left.

Comment: so what I mean by align left is, even when I fill the parent when I run the app, there is always some space to the left of the text view and I dont know why I can show you a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your xml file for that TextView

android:scrollHorizontally="true"

Or programatically use

setHorizontallyScrolling  method [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHorizontallyScrolling%28boolean%29)